# Windows 8.1 Enterprise activate error. The key is OEM

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Why I couldn't activate my Windows Enterprise 8.1 after format my laptop Acer Aspire. The key is OEM. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an OEM key to activate an Enterprise image, you need to use an Enterprise key.

Comment: OEM only for pro version?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in this comment.

Comment: I'm so disappointed . Then I'll crack it. Merci

Comment: Or you could, you know, purchase it legally.

Comment: I'm just kidding. I prefer Linux. I tried to help to my mate.

Comment: @Farrukh - Let us be productive.  Saying "I will crack it" is not productive.

Answer (score 1):

Some words more about ***"what's wrong?"***

> Windows 8.x enterprise doe not use the same key method as the OEM or retail version. it will have to be wiped when the evaluation period ends in 90 days. **It can not be converted to a retail version because the trial key is actually encrypted in the software binaries**. If you use a corporate windows 8.x enterprise version, that version will expect to contact a key server on the corporate network. If it fails it will be deactivate over some period of time.

Reference

- A [post](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2001321/validate-windows-windows-oem-key.html) on tomshardware site.